# How can you add custom permissions to the standard permissions tab?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, modern-experience, groups, sharepoint-permissions

How can you add custom permissions in the "Site Permissions" tab just like the standard three in the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can customize this SharePoint default panel to add your custom groups/permission levels on it.

However, you can access all your permissions by following below steps:

1. Click on settings (gear) icon
2. Click on "Site permissions"
3. Click on "Advanced permissions settings"

   [image]
4. It will take you to the site permissions page.

---

Alternatively, you can access the site permissions & groups pages using below shortcut URLs:

1. Site permissions: `<siteUrl>/wlive/_layouts/15/user.aspx`
2. Site groups: `<siteUrl>/wlive/_layouts/15/groups.aspx`